# Environment variable not loading correctly into 'process.env' in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, github-actions, .env

I'm attempting to set an environment variable for my Node.js application using GitHub Actions. However, when I run the workflow, it appears that the application isn't reading the variable correctly, as it returns an 'invalid token' error. Additionally, I'd like to know how to use a `.env` file to set this variable within GitHub Actions.

Here is the workflow:

```yaml
name: Pay and Connect Voucher Request

on:
    schedule:
        - cron: '00 20 * * 1-5'
  
jobs:
  request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: "18.15"

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Setting the environment variables
      run: |
       echo "AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN=$AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      env:
        AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN }}

    - name: Run Program
      run: npm start
```

This is the code I'm running from `src/index.ts`:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.configDotenv();

const requestURL: string =
    "https://uct.api.getslideapp.com/2/connect/vouchers/issue/";
const authorizationToken = process.env.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN;

async function sendRequest() {
    try {
        const { data, status } = await axios.post(
            requestURL,
            {},
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Origin: "https://app.payandconnect.co.za",
                    Referer: "https://app.payandconnect.co.za/u/vouchers",
                    Authorization: authorizationToken,
                },
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.log("message: ", error.response?.data);
        } else {
            console.log("unexpected error: ", error);
        }
    }
}

sendRequest();
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```bash
> pay-and-connect-plus-plus@1.0.0 start
> ts-node src/index.ts

TOKEN***
message:  { status: 'error', message: 'Token is invalid.' }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it's not reading the variable correctly. It looks like the value for the token is invalid

Comment: In your case, instead of setting `AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN` to `$GITHUB_ENV`, you can directly set it with `env` context. You just need to move the `env` with the step where it's needed and remove the step that's setting it to `$GITHUB_ENV`.

Comment: Is that token working locally for you? Have you verified that while setting the secret there are no extra newlines or spaces there?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. While I was troubleshooting the issue, I noticed that when I log in to the website where I obtained the API call, the token works. However, when I close the website and run the workflow separately, the token becomes invalid. I suspect that this issue might be related to the headers. 
The token does work locally on my machine.
What do you think might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, it seems that you are facing two issues with setting the environment variable for your Node.js application using GitHub Actions. The first issue is that the application is not reading the variable correctly, resulting in an 'invalid token' error. The second issue is that you would like to know how to use a .env file to set this variable within GitHub Actions.

To address the first issue, it appears that the environment variable `AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN` is not being set correctly in the GitHub Actions workflow. This could be causing the 'invalid token' error when the application tries to read the variable. Have you confirmed that the `AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN` secret is set properly in your GitHub repository secrets?

Now, regarding the second issue, to use a .env file to set the variable within GitHub Actions, you can use the `dotenv` package to load the variable from a .env file. However, I noticed a small typo in your code where you used `dotenv.configDotenv()` instead of `dotenv.config()`. Please update this line to `dotenv.config()` to correctly load the variable from the .env file.

Have you tried making these changes and see if they resolve the issues you are facing? Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. While I was troubleshooting the issue, I noticed that when I log in to the website where I obtained the API call, the token works. However, when I close the website and run the workflow separately, the token becomes invalid. I suspect that this issue might be related to the headers. 

Do you have any suggestions on how to can solve it from there?